# Sum of Fibonacci even number

Tags: ruby, fibonacci

I'm currently working on small ruby projects from project Euler site. I was given a task to sum even fibonacci numbers that are less than 4 millions. Unfortunately there is a small bug in my code, because when I change the limit e.i. to 100, it prints 188 instead of 44. Surprisingly this program gives the right answer but i don't really know in what way my code is wrong.

```
a=[]; a[0]=1; a[1]=1;
i = 1
while a[-1] < 608
  a[i+1]=(a[i] + a[i-1])
  i +=1
end
x = 0
a.each do |num|
  if num % 2 == 0
    x += num
  end
end
print "The sum of even Fibonacci number is: #{x}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the second iteration. You are stopping the generation of Fibonacci numbers when one of the numbers cross the limit (ie when the last number is > 100).

It turns out that after the generation step, the array is `[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144]`, this explains your wrong result 188 = 144+44.

So, your code works only when the last element generated is odd, which is the case in Euler's problem test. In order to correct that, change your second iteration from `a.each do ... end` to `a[0...-1].each do ... end` In order to iterate through the array except the last element.

Comment: I'm very thankful! I'm just making my first steps in this world and I'm very pleased that there are people like you, who help beginners.

Answer (score 1):

BTW I would recommend you not to use an array here.
You are just wasting memory and ruby is losing time on extending it (this can be solved via `Array.new(ARRAY_SIZE)`).

Since you don't actually need a fibbonaci sequence you can just have something like this:

```
LIMIT = 4_000_000
a = 1
b = 1
next_number = a + b
sum = 0
while next_number < LIMIT
  sum += next_number if next_number.even?
  a = b
  b = next_number
  next_number = a + b # or next_number += a
end
```

UPD. Oh my god I don't know why this question appeared in my feed. Sorry for necroposting:)